# Why is `this` not equal to `Object` and why is property `undefined`?

Tags: javascript, object

This object implements a pattern to provide event listeners. It works in at least IE 11 and Chrome.

But I don't understand why and I have 2 questions.

In the keypress event listener, there is an alert that shows that `this` is equal to `[object HTMLInputElement]` and `this.element` is `undefined`.

1. Why is `this` not equal to `Object`?
2. Why is `this.element` `undefined`? (Note it is initialized in the `init` method.)

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zuhgfd7/)

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function CustomEditor(id) {
    'use strict';
    this.element = null;
    this.id = id;
    this.init();
};

CustomEditor.prototype.addEvent = function (event, callback) {
    'use strict';
    return this.element.addEventListener(event, callback, false);
};

CustomEditor.prototype.init = function () {
    'use strict';
    this.element = document.getElementById(this.id);
    this.addEvent('keypress', this.onCustomKeyPress);
};


CustomEditor.prototype.onCustomKeyPress = function () {
    'use strict';
    // alert("keypress event handler");
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
    this.style.color = "#ff0";
    alert('this = ' + this + '\n\nthis.element = ' + this.element);
};


// create and initialize custom editor
ce = new CustomEditor('myInput1');
document.getElementById('myInput1').value = 'a';
alert('ce = ' + ce + '\n\nce.element = ' + ce.element);
```

**EDIT:** From the comments by @Bergi & @lombausch, I understand the misconception I had had around `this` and context (weekend warrior here). I made the following modification to my object and now `this` has the context I need. (I'm using `call` rather than `bind` so the code works with older browsers.)

```
MyObj.prototype.addEvent = function (event, callback, caller) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof window.addEventListener === 'function') {
        return this.element.addEventListener(event, function () {
            callback.call(caller);
        }, false);
    }
    // for older versions of IE, order of test is important
    return this.element.attachEvent('on' + event, function () {
        callback.call(caller);
    });
};
```

New [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2j916znm/1/)

**But a new Question:** What changes have to be made to the pattern for `onCustomKeypress` to have access to the event interface / object?

The event interface is the first argument of the event listener, but I can't seem to pass it to the callback function. For example, this does not work:

```
  MyObj.prototype.onCustomKeyPress = function (e) {
```

Comment: I assume you mean "equal to `ce`", not to `Object`?

Comment: That's just how event listeners work, they are called in context of the element they're bound to. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) for solutions - or do you really want to know *why*?

Comment: Is this confusing to you in general (as it is to most JavaScript newcomers), or specifically with respect to why `'use strict'` is not helping?

Comment: @Bergi, I understand that `ce` is the variable that references the object. The value of `this` inside the event handler would not know `ce`. What I'm trying to understand is why `this` is an `HTMLInputElement` and not my object? And by extension, why isn't `this.element`not an `HTMLInputElement` rather than being `undefined`?

Comment: because "this.onCustomKeyPress" method is called from HTMLInputElement context

Comment: javascript is not OOP and pretty much any object can call method of any other object with own context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (I'm using call rather than bind so the code works with older browsers.)

Why? `bind` is a lot simpler apparently. If you want it to work with older browsers, just include [this simple polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill) somewhere in your code.

> What changes have to be made to the pattern for onCustomKeypress to have access to the event interface / object?

None. The problem is still your `addEvent` function, which might now invoke the `callback` with the correct context but without the arguments. Two solutions:

- Use the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) instead:

  ```
  …(…, function() {
      callback.apply(caller, arguments);
  } …
  ```
- Just pass the event argument to `call` - it takes any number of normal arguments after the context:

  ```
  MyObj.prototype.addEvent = function(event, callback, caller) {
      'use strict';
      if (typeof window.addEventListener === 'function') {
          this.element.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
              callback.call(caller, e);
          }, false);
      } else {
          // for older versions of IE, order of test is important
          this.element.attachEvent('on' + event, function() {
              callback.call(caller, window.event);
          });
      }
  };
  ```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. (I had added the `e` as a parameter to the anonymous callback function but had miss adding it as a parameter to `call `.

Comment: Just now I posted a follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386665/how-to-use-removeeventlistener-when-event-handler-is-a-prototype-function) asking how to use `removeEventListener`. I thought you might know the answer.